# Is it possible to have an extension library dialog box within a repeat control?

Tags: lotus-domino, xpages

I'm running with an 8.5.3 UP1 server and I have a need to have many dialog boxes (for confirmation purposes) for a whole bunch of "action buttons" on an xpage.  The code for these dialog boxes is almost exactly the same with the exception of the confirmation message being different and the client-side JS function they are calling if the Yes button is selected.

Since I really hate repeating code over and over, I was wondering if it is at all possible to put a xe:dialog control within a repeat control and specify the message and function call from an array of values? I know I can't compute the ID of the dialog control and without that I'm not sure how I would reference the dialog to open and close it.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Make sure that you specify that the dialog box's property for keepComponents is set to False. You don;t have to do anything special for opening or closing the dialog box, just use whatever ID you give the dialog box in you client-side action to open the dialog box in the repeat such as `XSP.openDialog('#{id:myDialog}')`

The XPages renderer will automatically calculate the correct ID names for you.

Comment: Ok, I get that. But how do I reference the dialog from outside of the repeat control? In other words, I need to call XSP.openDialog("#{id:myDialog}") from my action button? Since there will be multiple dialogs, I don't know what name to use.

Comment: Ahh, I would be putting the button inside the repeating element so there is one button for each line of the repeat. A button outside would be difficult to do but not impossible. how would you know which line of repeat at act on when the users clicks the button

Comment: My action buttons are not so much buttons but rather links, in an unordered list which render into a drop down menu 3 levels deep. So I can't think of an easy way to put the repeat control within that.  You say it's not impossible to do if it is outside the repeat control, can you elaborate on that idea? My thought is I would reference the line in the repeat control based on a pre-determined index value (i.e. "Change to Draft" Button is button #12, etc..).  Thanks

Comment: @DanHerman so there could be twelve 'change to draft buttons' ? Sounds like a UI nightmare for the end user if they can't count :-)
My idea was that the ID for the dialog would be based on the UNID of each document then the button could be linked to `#{id:UNID}` somehow. Personally I'd look at the UI and think of a different way. a small list of link under each document ( that only appear when you hover over that line in the repeat ).

Comment: Dan - I don't know if this is helpful, but I did a video on selecting ID's from inside a repeat control:  http://notesin9.com/index.php/2011/04/01/notesin9-025-selecting-documents-from-a-repeat-control/ 
Maybe you can do something with that info.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I'll see if I can re-work the UI to get the buttons inside the repeat control. Either that or just grudgingly repeat the dialog a bunch of times.